# Index pattern is not matching in latest kibana version 6.3.0

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-6

In logstash template, I have below index patterns:

`"event-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"`

When I tried to create index pattern on kibana 6.3.0, then it is not matching.
Does anyone know how I can create an index pattern for event-2018.10.13 in kibana 6.3.0?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRACr.jpg)

Comment: why not use `event-*` as a pattern?

Comment: Yep, as suggested above simply use `event-*`

Comment: I am using the same, but when I am looking at index pattern created by kibana, unusual field are populating with "keyword". https://discuss.elastic.co/t/map-keyword-field-in-kibana-6-3-0/151821

Comment: Can you post the output of c:/elasticsearc/template.json you are using in logstash.conf ? As mentioned by David on the elastic discussion forum you need to modify your index template to 

`"index_patterns": [
      "event-*"
    ]`

 From Elasticsearch 5.0, 'string' type has been removed. The string field has been split into two new types: text, which should be used for full-text search, and keyword, which should be used for keyword search.

Comment: Disabling this is easy: all you need to do is to either map string fields explicitly or to use a dynamic template that matches all string fields. For instance the below dynamic template can be used to restore the same dynamic mappings that were used in Elasticsearch 2.x:

 {
   "match_mapping_type": "string",
   "mapping": {
  "type": "text"
   }
 }